# Não consigo ir buscar informação a uma base de dados MS SQL através de ODBC e com query builder do CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

Boas,

Estou a tentar criar uma página de login com o CodeIgniter.

Acontece que, para validar os dados inseridos, preciso de ir buscar informação a uma base de dados MS SQL através do ODBC. Ao usar o query builder do CodeIgniter, aparece-me o seguinte erro:

> Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::select()

Qual o motivo para que isto aconteça?

**Model**

```
class Utilizador_model extends CI_Model {

public function login($username,$password){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('utilizadores');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
     return $q->result_array();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do CI está utilizando? Pelo o que me lembro a partir da versão 3.1 não é mais possível utilizar o Query Builder do CI com o ODBC. Se for utilizar o query builder, tente utilizar o SQLSRV (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) invés do ODBC, deve funcionar.

Comment: Estou a usar a 3.1.10.

Comment: Eu experimentei sem a query builder do CI e está a funcionar

Comment: Então é exatamente esse o ponto. Nessa versão o Query Builder não funciona mais com o ODBC, se você não utilizar o Query Builder irá funcionar normalmente, ou você pode utilizar outro driver como o SQLSRV, para poder usar o QB.